Trouble Determining Dependent Side in One-to-One Relationship with Entity Framework Core
I'm currently working on a project using Entity Framework Core in a .NET Core application. I'm having trouble determining the dependent side in a one-to-one relationship between the User and Account entities. I tried configuring the entities and their relationships according to the established standards, but I'm encountering an error:

The dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one
relationship between 'Account.User' and 'User.Account'. To identify
the dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key
property...

My configuration classes look like this:
public class User : BaseModel
{
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
}

public class Account : BaseModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(u => u.Account)
            .WithOne(a => a.User)
            .HasForeignKey<Account>(a => a.UserId);
    }
}

public class AccountConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Account>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Account> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(a => a.User)
            .WithOne(u => u.Account);
    }
}

SQL to create tables:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts] 
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Accounts] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Accounts_Users] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id]) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_Accounts_UserId] 
ON [dbo].[Accounts] ([UserId]);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] 
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountId] INT NULL, -- This can be NULL if we set the FK on the Account table

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Users_Accounts] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([AccountId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Accounts] ([Id]) 
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_Users_AccountId] 
ON [dbo].[Users] ([AccountId]);


First of all, I don't see a point of creating two tables that only point to each other and doing contain any other columns. In such a case I also struggle to understand what depends on what. Can you add more meaningful fields to the tables? Can you please elaborate why do you think you need both User and Account?

Add a tag for the dbms used, the above syntax is product specific.
